# problems centos 7 httpd service restart

Tags: linux, apache, centos, centos7

when I type  **systemctl restart httpd** ,

I get the following error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

en when I type **systemctl status httpd.service**

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-01 00:45:46 COT; 16s ago
  Process: 1927 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23178 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1925 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1925 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Total requests: 657; Current requests/sec: -30.7; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"


Jul 01 00:45:46 sitio.co systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 01 00:45:46 sitio.co systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jul 01 00:45:46 sitio.co systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

for **journalctl -xe**

```
Jul 01 01:05:01 sitio.co CROND[2219]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/maldetect/maldet --mkpubpaths >> /dev/null 2>&1)
Jul 01 01:09:23 sitio.co systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 01 01:09:48 sitio.co postfix/qmgr[2155]: 968D275E: from=<root@sitio.co>, size=3215, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 01 01:09:48 sitio.co postfix/smtp[2303]: warning: database /etc/postfix/generic.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/generic
Jul 01 01:09:49 sitio.co postfix/smtp[2303]: 968D275E: to=<sistemas.revistas@correounivalle.edu.co>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.217.109]:587, delay=42
Jul 01 01:10:01 sitio.co systemd[1]: Created slice user-0.slice.
-- Subject: Unit user-0.slice has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit user-0.slice has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 01 01:10:01 sitio.co systemd[1]: Starting Session 76464 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-76464.scope has begun with start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-76464.scope has begun starting up.
Jul 01 01:10:01 sitio.co systemd[1]: Started Session 76464 of user root.
-- Subject: Unit session-76464.scope has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit session-76464.scope has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Jul 01 01:10:01 sitio.co CROND[2306]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/maldetect/maldet --mkpubpaths >> /dev/null 2>&1)
```

and for **systemctl status httpd.service -l**

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-07-01 01:09:24 COT; 4min 24s ago
  Process: 2296 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23178 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2294 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2294 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Total requests: 657; Current requests/sec: -30.7; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
```

> Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvNs.png): httpd.service: main process
> exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvNs.png): Failed to start The Apache HTTP
> Server.
>
> Jul 01 01:09:24 sitio.co systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvNs.png): Unit httpd.service entered failed
> state.

look the last logs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqvNs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ4gW.png)

Comment: Post `journalctl -xe` and `systemctl status httpd.service -l` command output in question.

Comment: Check the server log files.

Comment: @Pandurang edited!

Comment: @kjohri now in the image are the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop the Apache httpd service and check semaphore usage owned by the apache user.

```
ipcs -s
```

Execute the following command to clear semaphore used by Apache user.

```
ipcs -s | awk -v user=apache '$3==user {system("ipcrm -s "$2)}'
```

You can refer [Link](https://serverfault.com/questions/991946/no-space-left-on-device-ah00023-couldnt-create-the-mpm-accept-mutex-when-re) for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, now it says "Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-07-01 01:49:09 COT; 3min 21s ag"
but the server continues "The service is not available. Please try again later."

Comment: excuse me i added a new image

Comment: don't worry about that, i fixed it

Answer (score 0):

fix error  by running
$ apachectl configtest